# Why isn't my listview selectable?

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a custom CursorAdapter and it looks like :

```
public class LabelAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

Context con;
LayoutInflater mFactory;

public AlarmTimeAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    con = context;
    mFactory = LayoutInflater.from(con);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {


    final String label2 = cursor.getString(AlarmData.ALARM_TITLE_INDEX);

    ..code to fill in the textview with whats in the cursor


}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) { 
    View ret = mFactory.inflate(R.layout.item_lv, parent, false);

    return ret;
}

}
```

my item_lv looks like:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:focusable="true"
    >

         <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

When I call :

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview); //Listview is in the main.xml file
lv.setAdapter(new LabelAdapter(this, mCursor);
lv.setFocusable(true);
```

The items in the listview aren't selectable.. does anyone know whats wrong? I've set the items focusable, but they aren't able to be clicked. Help! Thanks!

Comment: for this you need to implement `onItemClickListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `onItemClickListener` to your listView-

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position,
            long arg3) {
    });
```

Comment: i mean I have that too in my main call .. it still doesn't click

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:focusable="true" from RelativeLayout for your item.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer is really simple. Set the textview in the .xml should be

Android:Clickable = "True"

Reason for this is that if you are putting this as rows they have to be clickable in order to recognize click events.